# Is there a way to temporarily remove items from a session and re-add after code has run

Tags: python, django

I am working on an e-commerce site, using Django. I am trying to add a custom order to the bag which is happening, however now I cannot add other products to the bag when the custom order is in the bag. I was thinking if I removed the custom_order from the session, it would allow the other code to run, in order to add products to the bag.

context.py

```
from decimal import Decimal
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from products.models import Product
from custom_order.models import CustomOrder

def bag_contents(request):

    bag_items = []
    total = 0
    bag = request.session.get('bag', {})

    print(bag)
     
    if 'custom_order' in bag:
        custom_order_id = bag['custom_order'] 
        custom_order = CustomOrder.objects.get(pk=custom_order_id)
        total += custom_order.price
        bag_items.append({
            'product_id': custom_order.product_id,
            'custom_order_id': custom_order_id,
            'category': custom_order.category,
            'material': custom_order.material,
            'individual_total': custom_order.price,
            'quantity': 1,
            'product_name': custom_order.product_name
        })
    else:
        for product_id, quantity in bag.items():
            product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
            if isinstance(quantity, int) and isinstance(product.price, Decimal):
                total += quantity * product.price
                individual_total = quantity * product.price
                product_count += quantity
                bag_items.append({
                'product_id': product_id,
                'quantity': quantity,
                'product': product,
                'individual_total': individual_total,
            })
    
    grand_total = total
    

    context = {
        'bag_items': bag_items,
        'grand_total': grand_total,
    }

    return context
```

View to add product to bag

```
def add_to_bag(request, product_id):
    """ Add a quantity of the specified product to the shopping bag """
    quantity = int(request.POST.get('quantity'))
    redirect_url = request.POST.get('redirect_url')
    
    bag = request.session.get('bag', {})

    if product_id in list(bag.keys()):
        bag[product_id] += quantity
    else:
        bag[product_id] = quantity

    request.session['bag'] = bag
    return redirect(redirect_url)
```

view to add custom_order to bag

```
def add_custom_order_to_bag(request, custom_order_id):
    """ Add a quantity of the specified product to the shopping bag """
    custom_order = CustomOrder.objects.get(pk=custom_order_id)
    bag = request.session.get('bag', {})

    bag['custom_order'] = custom_order_id
   
    request.session['bag'] = bag
    return redirect(reverse('view_bag'))
```

I have tried this:

```
def add_to_bag(request, product_id):
    """ Add a quantity of the specified product to the shopping bag """
    quantity = int(request.POST.get('quantity'))
    redirect_url = request.POST.get('redirect_url')
    
    bag = request.session.get('bag', {})

    custom_order_id = bag.pop('custom_order', None)

    if product_id in list(bag.keys()):
        bag[product_id] += quantity
    else:
        bag[product_id] = quantity

    if custom_order_id:
        bag['custom_order'] = custom_order_id

    request.session['bag'] = bag
    return redirect(redirect_url)
```

but it is not working, I am getting no errors so think the logic might be off!

Comment: Can't you just remove the `else` in your `bag_contents` view and add a condition in the loop like: `if product_id == 'custom_order': continue`? Also to keep things simpler why don't you just make the `bag` object further subdivided, something like `bag["custom_order"]` and `bag["normal_orders"]`?

Comment: Thanks this solved it, if it was the answer I would accept it.